# Download full text from tweepy API

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to download some tweets by using the tweepy API:

```
users = ['Samir_Madani', 'DanielMichael26', 'staunovo', 'Amena__Bakr', 'TopOilNews', 'emmarossthomas', 'OilXs', ]

for i in range(len(users)): 
df = pd.DataFrame([str(tweet.created_at) + ' ' + tweet.text + ' ' for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id = users[i], full_text = True, until='2020-10-01').items()], columns = ['Tweets'])
df.to_csv('Tweets_test'+ str(users[i]))
```

By doing this, I am actually able to download tweets but some of them are truncated. Is there a way to download the full tweet?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the full text of a tweet using tweepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161459/how-to-get-the-full-text-of-a-tweet-using-tweepy)

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to pass `tweet_mode='extended'` while initializing `Api`:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([str(tweet.created_at) + ' ' + tweet.text + ' ' for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, tweet_mode='extended', id = users[i], full_text = True, until='2020-10-01').items()], columns = ['Tweets'])
```