# How to get the whole tweet using tweepy instead of part of the tweet with a link

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

Firstly, I do realize that there's a similar question but using the Twython library, not Tweepy.
Also, I have seen [How to get the full text of a tweet using tweepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161459/how-to-get-the-full-text-of-a-tweet-using-tweepy) But, adding `, tweet_mode='extended'` after `count=count` below gives me an error: `AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'text'`
Here is what I have:

```
fetched_tweets = api.search(q, lang = 'en', count=count)

for tweet in fetched_tweets:
    parsed_tweet = {}
    parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text

    line = re.sub('@[\w]+', '', tweet.text)
    target.write(line+"\n")
    target.write("--------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    tweets.append(line)
```

So, I am creating a list of these tweets, however some of the tweets appear as the following:

> ADAM ARON CONFIRMED IF WE VOTE YES ON THE 500M, AMC PLEDGES NOT TO DILUTE ANY OF IT IN CALENDAR YEAR 2021.
>
> GIVE TH… h t t p s : / / t . c o / t D i T u x f d F g
> (I had to add spaces between the letters of the link)

It should instead read:

> ADAM ARON CONFIRMED IF WE VOTE YES ON THE 500M, AMC PLEDGES NOT TO
> DILUTE ANY OF IT IN CALENDAR YEAR 2021.
>
> GIVE THAT MAN HIS SHARES.
>
> Within the legal confines of being a CEO, he is on our side and wants
> the same thing we do.
>
> changing my vote to Yes.
>
> $amc #amc

Comment: From what I understand, it has to do with extended tweets. But, I thought that the links are only for when there is a picture or a video included in the tweet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the full text of a tweet using tweepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161459/how-to-get-the-full-text-of-a-tweet-using-tweepy)

Comment: adding ", tweet_mode='extended'" returns an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, I was able to change `fetched_tweets = api.search(q, lang = 'en', count=count)` to `fetched_tweets = api.search(q, lang = 'en', count=count, tweet_mode='extended')`, and also change `tweet.text` to `tweet.full_text`.