# tweepy Status object (tweet) has no attribute .text

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets

Using the Tweepy Python library I connected a Twitter account's credentials and stream real-time tweets related to a term of interest and then, I want to save them into a .txt file.

and then I want to read all the data we gathered into a pandas DataFrame

How could I do it, please.

This is my code:

```py
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id='CarrefourFrance',tweet_mode='extended').items(33)

with open('t.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tweet in cursor:
        try:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(tweet.text.encode("utf-8")))
        except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
            print(e)
```

This is the error: `AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: what makes you think each tweet (a `Status` object) should have an attribute `.text`?  (and why are you importing `io` when you don't use it?)

Comment: the io was from previously copied code and I just found this one here and I just tried it

Comment: Actually this is odd: a .text property *ought* to exist per a quick skim of the docs.  add `print(dir(tweet), tweet)` before `print(e)` and get a look at the failing case.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161459/how-to-get-the-full-text-of-a-tweet-using-tweepy ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try change `tweet.text` to `tweet.full_text`

Or something like this:

```
results = api.search(q=query, lang=language, count=tweetCount, tweet_mode='extended')
for tweet in results:
        print(tweet.full_text)
```

For reference: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/878

And see the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#extended-mode) for extended mode:

> When using extended mode, the text attribute of Status objects returned by tweepy.API methods is replaced by a full_text attribute, which contains the entire untruncated text of the Tweet.

Comment: I don't use these libraries, but a glance at the docs suggested it might be `full_text` ?

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for answering me ... but it gaves me this error : AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'tweet'

Comment: thaaaaaaank you so much it works... but how now to read it with pandas ... and sorry for reansewing

Comment: Pandas uses mainly `.csv` file and you are trying to save it in `.txt` file, maybe you should implement a different idea.

Comment: csv is just a text file with a comma separating fields and it is perfectly possible to read a file linewise into a pandas df (one entry per column).  But this is really a separate question, and @tous is better off following a tutorial for it or having a go and coming back if something doesn't work.  Note that there's nothing stopping you sticking the tweet straight  into a df if that makes more sense in your case: dfs are just objects, and you can add rows trivially.

Comment: I am following this tutorial that's why : https://medium.com/future-vision/visualizing-twitter-interactions-with-networkx-a391da239af5